# Differences in OpenGL on Qt 5.2 and on 5.10

Tags: qt, opengl

I’m working now on some project built on Qt 5.2.1.  The project makes some basic rendering (using QPixmap, GraphicsScene, etc). The goal is to switch this mechanism to OpenGL as quickly as possible. In addition we plan to move the whole project to Qt 5.10.

Is there some benefit first moving to Qt 5.10 and only then switch to OpenGL over first switching to OpenGL and afterwards move to Qt 5.10?

Is there possibility of some unexpected difficulties if we first switch to OpenGL (on Qt 5.2.1) and only then upgrading to Qt 5.10 (some features got deprecated or some new nice-to-use features appear)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with OpenGL on Qt is it being full of both old and new bugs, poor integration capabilities, poor platform support (Intel=NOPE) and no error handling of Qt-internals (e.g. context creation). At least of you use the built-in OpenGL-widgets.

That said there is much development going on right now of the Qt-OpenGL support, judging from which Qt-version certain OpenGL related features I have found in he manual. If you must use Qt-OpenGL, I would assume you get most features and few(er) bugs jumping onto latest and greatest.